# What does the integer 2 do in 4.to_s(2) in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, binary

This is from an exercise on CodeWars. The task is to implement a function that adds two numbers together and returns their sum in binary.

Here is my solution in Ruby.

```
def add_binary(a,b)
  binary_result = (a + b).to_s(2) 
end
```

What does the argument `(2)` do on the `to_s` method?

For instance:

```
a = 2
b = 2
```

I can follow that the result the string `"4"` but I do not understand what is happens with the `(2)` argument to get string: binary value `"100"`.

I have tried to look at the Ruby docs under integer.

https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Integer.html#method-i-to_s

Here is the `(2)` is to refering to base 10. How does it work? What does the code do with the `"4"` string?

Comment: What are you asking exactly? You acknowledge in your question that `2` is the base specifier, and link to the documentation that confirms this. If your question is simply "Why is 4 equal to 100 in binary", that has nothing to do with Ruby.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `2` refers to base 2, a string representation of the actual bits that are set:

```
0.to_s(2) # => "0"
1.to_s(2) # => "1"
2.to_s(2) # => "10"
3.to_s(2) # => "11"
4.to_s(2) # => "100"
5.to_s(2) # => "101"
6.to_s(2) # => "110"
7.to_s(2) # => "111"
```

> How does it work? What does the code do with the "4" string?

You'll need to study how bytes are represented. It's essential in programming in many fields to know at least the binary, decimal and hexadecimal representations of a number and be able to make sense of them. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix will get you started.

`to_s(n)` is very useful for many other uses though, so I'd recommend making the effort to get familiar with it.

Comment: Thank you for your comment,  I will look into these representations.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix

Answer (score 0):

The argument `to_s` takes is the base for the conversion. `2` will render a binary result. `10` is the default value.

The binary representation of `4` is `100`.

```
1 0 0
-----
4 2 1
```

Comment: Interesting, thanks!